# Dynamic object creation pattern - I love

Tags: design-patterns, oop

Recently I came up with the idea of simple pattern for dynamic creation of object. And I real love it.
I am sure that that "wheel" was invented and named. Could someone could point to some GOF pattern?

Problem: have huge number of objects that I don't want to have all initialized at the beginning. All are instances of one class.

I want to use an object and then free the memory (or allow garbage collection),
each object is correlated to some string, so I have a map ({"str1", obj1}, {"str2",obj2},...)
When the request comes with str1 I need to return obj1,....
I could have (pseudocode)

```
if(str == str1)
     return new Obj(obj1_init_params);  
else if(str == str2)  
    return new Obj(obj2_init_params);
```

...

However this is:

1. Inefficient - to go over all if conditions.
2. Ugly:)

To solve 1. you could use map:

```
map.put(str1, new Obj(obj1_init_params))
map.put(str2, new Obj(obj2_init_params))
```

then:

```
map.get(str1)
```

This is fast solution but ALL IS ONCE created not on demand. So....

Create a wrapper interface:

```
 IWrapper {
    Obj getObj();
}
```

Then I put it in map:

```
 map.put("str1", new IWrapper(){Obj getObj() {return new Object(object1_params)};
```

Now I am in home:

1. Fast: map.get("str1").getObj();
2. Dynamic - getObj() <- creation of object is postponed.

It is so simple, nice that someone had named it before. 
I am java programmer, so it work nice here. Can you came with similarly elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** I've mixed "what" with "how", originally.

*What* have you achieved?  A [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).
*How* have you achieved it?  Through the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) (as many others have already written).

**UPDATE** You can use the standard [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface instead of `IWrapper`:

```
map.put(str, new Callable<Obj>() { Obj call() { return new Obj(str); } });
```

Comment: very nice explanation, generally I know factory, and lazy evaluation (which terrifies me  as always my first thought is Singleton Pattern - which I started to hate). But I could not fit my concept into them, as it is composition of both. Simple "what" and "how" view makes all clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gadolin I've added a note about the `Callable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is a factory pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

> The factory pattern is a creational design pattern used in software development to encapsulate the processes involved in the creation of objects.
>   The creation of an object often requires complex processes not appropriate to include within a composing object.
>
> The object's creation may lead to a significant duplication of code, may require information not accessible to the composing object, may not provide a sufficient level of abstraction, or may otherwise not be part of the composing object's concerns.
>
> Some of the processes required in the creation of an object include determining which object to create, managing the lifetime of the object, and managing specialized build-up and tear-down concerns of the object.

Answer (score 1):

As other have said before, this is called "[Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)". Well done on figuring that out for yourself.

If you want to take this one step further, create a map which just contains the class name (a String). That allows you to read the names from a file and you end up with "[Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)" which leads to "[Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection)".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like an [object factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29).

Answer (score 0):

I remember writing a CodeProject article a long time ago about factories. You could take a look at it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/all_kinds_of_factories.aspx.

Also, DO NOT overdo it. There's an excellent article on factoryfactories on http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12 to give you an idea on how you could go too far in abstracting things.